# Пытаюсь преобразовать ссылку через .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, modx, mod-rewrite

Помимо ЧПУ, которые уже стоят на сайте:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?q=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Необходимо сократить ссылку вида [http://site.ru/оne/two/](http://site.ru/%D0%BEne/two/) ,таким образом  http://site.ru/two/ . Спасибо за помощь.

Answer (score 0):

Заходишь в системные настройки, в фильтре выбираешь "дружественный url", и там ищешь строку "Использовать вложенные URL" и ставишь значение "нет".